# rails3.1 - appending queries to an activerecord object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In rails 3.1, i am using activerecord to extract user records in a list based on certain conditions. Eg:

```
users = User.where("points > 10")
```

What i want is, depending on the number of results returned, to append the results of a second query to the object in the controller. So, for example if the first query returns fewer than 5 records, it'd want to append the results of

```
users = User.where("points > 5 and points < 11")
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
users = Users.where("points > 10")
if foo
  users << Users.where("points > 5 and points < 11")
end
```

Comment: doesnt that just add just one extra record with all the appended records inside?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [ActiveRecord scopes](http://www.edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/index.html).